# Flutter route get wrong

Tags: flutter, dart

```
children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/bg.png',
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                final player = AudioPlayer();
                player.setAsset('assets/sound.wav');
                player.play();
                SystemChannels.platform
                    .invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 220, top: 205),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/keluar.png',
                  width: 148,
                  height: 35,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                final player = AudioPlayer();
                player.setAsset('assets/sound.wav');
                player.play();
                Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                    reverseTransitionDuration:
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                        const Home(),
                    transitionsBuilder:
                        (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                      const begin = Offset(4.0, 2.0);
                      const end = Offset.zero;
                      const curve = Curves.easeInOutSine;

                      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end)
                          .chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

                      return SlideTransition(
                        position: animation.drive(tween),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    }));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 400, top: 205),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/lagi.png',
                  width: 195,
                  height: 35,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Good morning all brothers
I want to ask, there are two buttons: the "exit" button and the "learn again" button. For the "learn again" button, it's correct that if you click it, the "home" page appears. While the "exit" button, if you click it, the result is the same, it displays "home" too.
Where do you think the error in my code is?
Thank you all brother.

Answer (score 1):

If you call pop, Flutter will navigate you to the previous screen. If your previous screen is the home screen, indeed, it will navigate you to the home screen.